# Paperclip to s3 quickly and without

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, delayed-job

I have an application where I allow people to upload images and then resize them. It is written in rails and is largely based on http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images

It is currently storing files on Amazon S3 and everything is working but it takes forever: a 14kb file takes 14 seconds to get stored in S3 (I could almost live with that) a 750KB file takes 3 minutes to get stored in S3 (Young programmer gets killed by boss...)

The requirements are:

```
* The images need to be associated against my rails model like standard paperclip
* I need to be able to display the image as soon as possible so that I can let the user resize it, I cannot just assign it to a background job because I need to display it ASAP.
* I am hosting on heroku (cedar stack) so can only use the file system temporarily.
```

I have looked up a bunch of tutorials online and searched and it seems that most of them suggest using something like https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin
This however will still be quite a slow approach because first you have to send the file to S3 (big file takes about 30 seconds from New Zealand :) then you have to select the croppable area and click submit. Then the heroku server will download the original image of S3 and crop it and then send it back which will all take time.

The first step can't happen as a background process because I need to view the image so I can crop it (the second part probably could happen as a background process).

I am currently thinking that a good approach would be to just set up paperclip to upload and process the images on the temporary storage provided by my cedar heroku server. Then every couple of minutes I could have a background process running that looks for files on the heroku server and sends them to the S3 server. It will need a few small tweaks to sometimes look on the file system rather than S3 for an image but it should be doable.

I have never actually used DJ before. Has anyone tried this approach with heroku and S3?

Comment: I am also looking to resolve the same issue? how did you end up doing this ?